# My posts are being deleted for no good reason

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

Please excuse the woefully insufficient academic quality of my words.

My deleted answer: [What are the philosophical implications of the Halting Problem?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/3214/what-are-the-philosophical-implications-of-the-halting-problem/94011#94011)

> [...] Your post is based on an insufficient understanding of the matter. – Philip Klöcking 2 days ago

**I address that objection here:**

MIT Professor Michael Sipser has agreed that the following verbatim
paragraph is correct:

> If simulating halt decider H correctly simulates its input D until H
> correctly determines that its simulated D would never stop running
> unless aborted then H can abort its simulation of D and correctly
> report that D specifies a non-halting sequence of configurations.

When we see this notion of a halt decider applied to the embedded copy of Linz H within Linz Ĥ then we can see that the ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⟨Ĥ⟩ input to embedded_H specifies recursive simulation that never reaches its own final state of ⟨Ĥ.qy⟩ or ⟨Ĥ.qn⟩.

Ĥ.q0 ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⊢* H ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⊢* Ĥ.qy ∞ 
Ĥ.q0 ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⊢* H ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⊢* Ĥ.qn

**When Ĥ is applied to ⟨Ĥ⟩      // subscripts indicate unique finite strings**
Ĥ copies its input ⟨Ĥ<sub>0</sub>⟩ to ⟨Ĥ<sub>1</sub>⟩ then H simulates ⟨Ĥ<sub>0</sub>⟩ ⟨Ĥ<sub>1</sub>⟩

**Then these steps would keep repeating: (unless their simulation is aborted)**
Ĥ<sub>0</sub> copies its input ⟨Ĥ<sub>1</sub>⟩ to ⟨Ĥ<sub>2</sub>⟩ then H<sub>0</sub> simulates ⟨Ĥ<sub>1</sub>⟩ ⟨Ĥ<sub>2</sub>⟩
Ĥ<sub>1</sub> copies its input ⟨Ĥ<sub>2</sub>⟩ to ⟨Ĥ<sub>3</sub>⟩ then H<sub>1</sub> simulates ⟨Ĥ<sub>2</sub>⟩ ⟨Ĥ<sub>3</sub>⟩
Ĥ<sub>2</sub> copies its input ⟨Ĥ<sub>3</sub>⟩ to ⟨Ĥ<sub>4</sub>⟩ then H<sub>2</sub> simulates ⟨Ĥ<sub>3</sub>⟩ ⟨Ĥ<sub>4</sub>⟩...

Once one accepts the notion of a simulating halt decider that continues to correctly simulate its input until it correctly determines that this simulated input would never stop running then the conventional halting problem proofs are refuted because their "impossible" input becomes correctly construed as specifying recursive simulation (same idea as infinite recursion).

> In computability theory, the halting problem is the problem of
> determining, from a description of an arbitrary computer program and
> an input, whether the program will finish running, or continue to run
> forever. Alan Turing proved in 1936 that a general algorithm to solve
> the halting problem for all possible program-input pairs cannot exist.
>
> For any program H that might determine if programs halt, a
> "pathological" program P, called with some input, can pass its own
> source and its input to H and then specifically do the opposite of
> what H predicts P will do. **No H can exist that handles this case**
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

```
int D(int (*M)())
{
  if ( H(M, M) )
    return 0;
  return 1;
}

int main() 
{ 
  Output((char*)"Input_Halts = ", D(D));  
}
```

H bases its analysis of its input D on the behavior of  its correct simulation of D.  H finds that D remains stuck in infinitely recursive simulation (shown below) until H aborts its simulation of D.

(a) D calls H that simulates D with an x86 emulator
(b) that calls a simulated H that simulates D with an x86 emulator
(c) that calls a simulated H that simulates D with an x86 emulator ...
**Until the executed H recognizes this repeating state, aborts its simulation of D and returns 0.**

This source-code proves that Sipser_H does correctly simulate its input Sipser_D and Sipser_H does correctly determine that Sipser_D would never stop running unless its simulation of Sipser_D is aborted.

**Complete halt deciding system (Visual Studio Project) Sipser version**
(a) x86utm operating system
(b) x86 emulator adapted from libx86emu to compile under Windows
(c) Several halt deciders and their sample inputs contained within Halt7.c
(d) The execution trace of Sipser_H applied to Sipser_D is shown in Halt7_Sipser.txt
https://liarparadox.org/2022_10_08.zip

## Peter Linz Turing machine version of H and P is H and Ĥ.

[image]

**Linz, Peter 1990.** An Introduction to Formal Languages and Automata. Lexington/Toronto: D. C. Heath and Company. (317-320)

Comment: The tone here is very aggressive -- I don't think Phillip's actions need _defending_ here. It seems like a handful of answers were deleted; maybe you could refocus this question on _why they were removed and what could be improved about them_ (rather than blaming moderators for doing their jobs).

Comment: @JosephWeissman I actually have refuted the halting problem proofs. Consistently everyone will not bother to spend five minutes to see that I am correct. It has taken me four full time years to boil my proof down to five minutes of straightforward software engineering. Even three months ago it would have taken an hour to understand my proof. Anyone that understands what infinite recursion is can understand my current proof.

Comment: I spent a few hours reviewing your software and it does not demonstrate what you claim. The fact that a program can spawn a slave process and under some conditions detect that the process has entered an infinite loop condition is not a refutation of the halting theorem.

Comment: @Bumble The fact that the correctly simulated program-under-test P cannot possibly reach the return value from simulating halt decider H makes it impossible for P "to do the opposite of whatever its halt decider decides" thus defeating all of the conventional proofs.  Halt7out.txt contains the execution trace of  H(P,P) when x86utm.exe is executed with Halt7.obj

Comment: You have changed the meaning of 'halting'. The pathological TM itself is supposed to do the opposite of what it decides, not some spawned subprocess whose execution state can be monitored and terminated by its parent. In any case, the Halting Theorem states merely that there cannot be a halting decider that works for any program and any data input to that program. Even if you can detect an infinite loop condition in some cases, this would not refute the theorem. You would need to exhibit a decider that works in all cases.

Comment: @Bumble **computation that halts** … the Turing machine will halt whenever it enters a final state. (Linz:1990:234) 

Linz, Peter 1990. An Introduction to Formal Languages and Automata. Lexington/Toronto: D. C. Heath and Company.

Comment: @Bumble I don't have the hundreds of man-years that it would take to solve the halting problem so my scope is refuting the conventional proofs. 

H computes the mapping from its input finite string P to its own reject state based on the fact that a correct simulation of 1 to ∞ steps of P by H never reaches the final state "return" instruction of P. 

The concept of Universal Turing machines accepts that the correct simulation of a machine description does provide the actual behavior of this machine description.

Comment: @Bumble "Even if you can detect an infinite loop condition in some cases, this would not refute the theorem." That I concretely show exactly how the halt status of the conventional "impossible" input can be determined **does refute the halting theorem** The non-halting condition is recursive simulation (comparable to infinite recursion) and not any mere loop.

Comment: @JosephWeissman Once one accepts the notion of a simulating halt decider that continues to correctly simulate its input until it correctly determines that this simulated input would never stop running then the conventional halting problem proofs are refuted because their "impossible" input becomes correctly construed as specifying recursive simulation (same idea as infinite recursion). **Within this definition the behavior of non-inputs is irrelevant.**

Comment: I locked this post because you continue to use this site to discuss your own understanding of highly technical proofs without presenting anything on the same level of formal rigour. That is not how the site is supposed to be used.

Answer (score 11):

There are very good reasons to delete these posts and I am glad you found your way here so that we can properly discuss them.

1. They miss the gist of the question. If the question asks for philosophical *implications* of the problem, it clearly asks for what to make of the consequences if we accept this is true. The question has never been about whether there are flaws.
2. You reposted something that was already deleted out of this reason instead of bringing it up here.
3. You do apparently ignore the formal nature of the whole problem. I linked a paper for you which explains *in detail* that the problem was first mentioned in principle by Kleene and later coined and proven to be undecidible by Davis, see [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/351270479_The_origins_of_the_halting_problem). I do not see how the remarks of Strachey are relevant to this.
4. The termination of a program is not the same as the halting of a TM.
5. This is not a blog to discuss your ideas, as you've been told many times over.

Comment: I have tried to get people to understand the philosophical implications of all of the instances of undecidability that are based on pathological self-reference (a) Gödel Incompleteness (b) The Tarski Undefinability theorem (c) The Halting problem proofs (d) The liar paradox. **The key philosophical issue is that everyone agrees that these things show that the concept of truth itself is incoherent.** That is why I have been working on these things since 1997.

Comment: "The termination of a program is not the same as the halting of a TM." If the program is Turing computable then they are computationally equivalent, thus my solution to [**An impossible program C. STRACHEY 1965**](https://academic.oup.com/comjnl/article/7/4/313/354243)
equally applies to the other instances of the halting problem proofs.

Comment: "The termination of a program is not the same as the halting of a TM." I have an alternative proof based on the Linz TM proof. The key point is that a simulating halt decider defeats the "do the opposite of whatever the halt decider decides" key element of all of the halting problem proofs.

Comment: @polcott The discussion on comp.theory you linked to already pointed out the main flaw: if your simulation does not have the same circularity as the original TM, ie. the TM is not *actually* computed, then you shifted goal posts as the problem has always been about TMs that *are actually computed*. You have shown *nothing at all* about the halting problem there, only your own poor understanding of the simple nature of TM.

Comment: I can't understand what you are saying. I have spent the last four years working in this full time.

Comment: @polcott Then maybe you should have read and understood papers like the one I linked before starting to work on that. Proofs work only in very specific formal frameworks. Changing the framework does not refute the proof. This is consistently what you do not understand across all your work.

Comment: I have been studying the Peter Linz proof since 2004.

Comment: Then you should mention this proof and be able to tell how it maps to the original proof by Davis and maybe even the original printing and satisfaction problems by Turing in the first place, not throw code at us.

Comment: @polcott My suspicion still is you use *code* without understanding what it does on the basic level while the problem is all about the basic level. Also, see my last comment. Forgot to tag you.

Comment: I graduated with a 3.52 GPA on a 4.0 scale in computer science. I wrote the x86utm operating system. I worked on the NPOESS satellite system. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPOESS system

Comment: @polcott Mate, nobody questions that you may be a terrific programmer. Those with knowledge in the field question that your "solutions" have the same formal structure *at the fundamental level* as the problems they supposedly solve. The question never was whether one can avoid certain problems ocurring in principle. **That possibility is trivially there.** The question is whether it can be avoided *within the exact same formal structure*. And maybe you even found a flaw in Linz' version, cannot speak to that, at all. That is still irrelevant as long as there is no proven equivalence to Davis'.

Comment: The Linz proof is sufficient. All other proofs including STRACHEY 1965 are computationally equivalent. The key aspect that I have defeated of all of these proofs is the input that a simulating halt decider simulates cannot possibly reach the return value from the halt decider thus cannot "do the opposite of whatever the halt decider decides".

Comment: The best that I can tell from the paper that you cited the Davis proof is never presented it is only talked about. Also this same paper cites: STRACHEY 1965.

Comment: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/3214/what-are-the-philosophical-implications-of-the-halting-problem/94011#94011<br>
**Your post is based on an insufficient understanding of the matter. – 
Philip Klöcking 2 days ago**

I prove otherwise above

Comment: Theoretical computer science is a mathematical subject with an established set of models that are, frankly, independent of practical computer programming. C code, despite standards and applied [formal verification techniques](https://compcert.org/), is not considered in the same domain as TMs. This isn't entirely unreasonable: mathematically speaking, digital computers are finite state machines and, in the absence of external input, the question of halting is trivially decidable. Not translating arguments to standard models will keep them from being considered seriously.

Comment: @polcott See the last comment, which blasts into the same horn as my objections.

Comment: See the answer that I just provided below

Comment: @DanielMGessel Please examine the answer that I provided below. It seems to me that you are saying that unless my H is a Turing computable function that it would not be a rebuttal of the halting theorem. I agree. I have spent many months making sure that H is a pure function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function Reviewers on SE indicate that this is a good measure of TM computability.

Comment: As long as my halt decider H is Turing computable then any objection that my work does not apply to Turing machines is overcome.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking The notion of a simulating halt decider refutes all of the HP proofs that I am aware of. **MIT Professor Sipser has agreed that the notion of a simulating halt decider is correct. (see quote in my answer below)** The last time that I checked his book was the best selling book on the theory of computation.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking I am responding to your reason for locking the post. When the notion of a simulating halt decider affirmed by Professor Sipser is applied to the sufficiently rigorous Linz proof then it becomes obvious to anyone with sufficient technical competence that the ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⟨Ĥ⟩ correctly simulated by embedded_H never reaches its final state ⟨Ĥ.qy⟩ or ⟨Ĥ.qn⟩ and halts because it remains stuck in recursive simulation (as shown above) that cannot possibly reach any final state.

Comment: If I was completely wrong then the author of the best selling book on the theory of computation would not have agreed that the most important aspect of my proof is correct. https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Theory-Computation-Sipser/dp/8131525295